# How do I handle dependencies in Puppet?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

In my puppet manifect I want to use [`dirtree`](https://github.com/AlexCline/puppet-dirtree) function like

```
#don't know which syntax is right, but seems like both of them have no effect  
include AlexCline/dirtree
include AlexCline_dirtree

class sw_mage_deploy {
    $deploy_folder = '/var/www/html'

    file { dirtree($deploy_folder):
        ensure => directory,
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => 755,
    } 
}
```

And in my Modulefile I have

```
dependency 'AlexCline/dirtree', '>= 0.2.1'
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
==> default: Error: Unknown function dirtree at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-bcfd
1f8b7eed950360c8143b9e421347/sw_mage_deploy/manifests/init.pp:15 on node vagrant
-vm
```

Tried [this](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html) article, but it seem to be irrelevant. Because it covers class inclusion and I need method inclusion.

As a side question I would really appreciate a link to puppet tutorial for very beginners, because googling doesn't really help and all docs seem to admit some obvious knowledge minimum which I seem to miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE* I am certainly not a puppet guru, been learning for few months, so cannot really address a tutorial and might not use the best practise.

on the first part of the question: **how to handle dependencies in Puppet**

I know of 2 ways:

1. use http://librarian-puppet.com (I do not really use it mylself so I might need to be corrected) which will manage dependencies from a Modulefile, a bit like you seem to describe. Using it with Vagrant, you need to install and configure it (using shell script) - [a plugin](https://github.com/mhahn/vagrant-librarian-puppet) exists which manages this part so this is surely a good option to look
2. currently, I am managing dependencies through normal `puppet module install' in shell script. Run a shell script from Vagrant which will install all modules, puppet takes care of all modules dependencies (if any) as they are declared from the individual module. An example of such script is

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;

   if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/example42-perl ]; then
     puppet module install example42-perl --version 2.0.20
   fi

   if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/puppetlabs-apache ]; then
     puppet module install puppetlabs-apache --version 1.5.0
   fi

   if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/puppetlabs-java ]; then
     puppet module install puppetlabs-java --version 1.4.1
   fi
   ```

on the second part of the question: **issue with using the dirtier function**

- install the module as any other module `puppet module install AlexCline-dirtree` (if you do not have puppet on your host, use your VM and copy the /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules to your shared folder /vagrant/modules)
- declare the following in your `Vagrantfile`

  ```
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "base.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --trace"
  end
  ```

and make sure you have created the `puppet/manifests/base.pp` file and the `puppet/modules` directory with the module you have installed

- define your puppet file

  ```
  class sw_mage_deploy {

      $deploy_folder = "/var/www/html"
      $dirtree = dirtree($deploy_folder)

  #    file { ["$dirtree"] :
  #        ensure => directory,
  #        owner  => "root",
  #        group  => "root",
  #        mode   => 755;
  #    } 

      ensure_resource('file', $dirtree, {
          'ensure' => 'directory',
          owner  => "root",
          group  => "root",
          mode   => 755
      })


  } 

  include sw_mage_deploy
  ```

As `$dirtree` returns an array, you cannot use it directly in your file block (it will try to concatenate all values from your array into a single value) but use the [ensure_resource function](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#ensure_resource) that can apply this for an array of resource

It is true that if you do not apply a variable, the following works

```
file { [ '/var/www',
         '/var/www/html',]:
           ensure => directory,
           ...
```

There might be way to bind the variable (which is an array) to be used like this, but I dont know how.

Comment: Looks like that is not addressing my issue, I do not want to install dependencies by hands, I want puppet to install them for me. Or that is not what supposed to happen and all dependencies should be added by myself?

Comment: We can maybe discuss details here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90452/puppet-dependency-issue

Answer (score 1):

The `include()` function does not do what you think it does.  It is for causing Puppet *classes* to be included in the *catalog* for the target node.  It has nothing whatever to do with the availability of custom functions within your manifests, notwithstanding that those functions are distributed in Puppet modules.

Moreover, for what it's worth, *neither* of the forms you presented looks like it should work.  Puppet ought not to accept either, as it is doubtful that a class having either of the specified names is available to include.

You do not need any special code in your manifests to use a custom function.  You just call it.  However, the function must first be installed into Puppet, which is a separate step from installing the module in which it resides (or it is in some versions of Puppet, anyway).  For functions distributed in modules, this is normally accomplished via pluginsync, but that does depend on having the Puppet agent running on the puppetmaster server.  You may need to restart the master afterward.